# Sort docs by array length in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a simple schema of post, which contains an array of Users ID who liked this post :

```
const PostSchema = new Schema({

title:{type: String, required: true},
content:    {type: String, required: true },
tags:       [{type:String}],
author:     {type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:"User", required:true},
likes:      [{ type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:"User", required:false}],
createTime: {type:Date, default:Date.now}
```

})

I want to order my docs my likes count, in other words sort my posts by likes array length. I try something like this but it doesn't work:

```
// @route  GET api/posts

router.get('/',(req, res)=>{

  Post.aggregate([{ $addFields: {likesCount:{$size:"likes"}} }]);
  Post.find()
    .populate('author','name email')
    .sort({likesCount:1})
    .then(posts=> res.json(posts))
    .catch(err=>console.log(err))
  })
```

I do not have idea how make it correctly. Please any help. Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
Post.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Author.collection.name,
    "let": { "author": "$author" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$_id", "$$author" ] } } },
      { "$project": { "name": 1, "email": 1 }}
    ],
    "as": "author",
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$author" },
  { "$addFields": { "likesCount": { "$size": "$likes" }}},
  { "$sort": { "likesCount": 1 }}
])
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems too difficult for me. Could you tell me how just add field  likesCount  by using aggregation please. I suppose then I can  write something like       Post.find().sort({likesCount:1})   and it will be much more   understandable for me

Comment: It is an aggregation query works same as find but mostly used to reshape the data format. So instead of `populate` I have used `$lookup` here and added a field `likesCount` and then made `$sort` with it.